# tkinter: как поставить текст и кнопку в центр?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
window = Tk()
window.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
window.title("Python app")

lbl = Label(window, text="Click to start checking for parking payments", font=("Arial Bold", 50))  
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)  

def buttonClick():

 f1 = open('C:/Users/Kate/Desktop/carnumbers.txt')
 f2 = open('C:/Users/Kate/Desktop/test.txt')
 line1 = next(f1)
 line2 = next(f2)

 if line1 == line2:

     print("equal")
 else:
     print("different")

btn = Button(window, text="Start", command=buttonClick)
btn.grid(column=0, row=2)  

window.mainloop()
```

Пробовала разные методы, но не получаеться поставить текст с первой строки и книпку со второй по средине.
Новичок в Thinker.
Буду очень благодарна за любую помощь!

Comment: запустил код - текст с первой строки, кнопка в середине второй. Что не устраивает?

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, что требуется сделать.
В этом случае надо использовать менеджер геометрии .pack() вместо .grid() и с его помощью поместить виджеты вверх в центр.
То есть, вместо

```
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

и

```
btn.grid(column=0, row=2)
```

сделать

```
lbl.pack(side=TOP)
```

и

```
btn.pack(side=TOP)
```

Comment: Exception has occurred: TclError
cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
  File "C:\Users\Kate\Desktop\2.py", line 99, in <module>
    btn.grid(column=0, row=2)

Comment: Получаю следующую ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка появляется из-за того, что в одном фрейме может быть использован только один менеджер геометрии - или pack или grid. В этом случае могу посоветовать создать объект-рамку Frame(), в котором разместить надписи по центру. А сам объект Frame() разместить на главном окне -

```
f=tkinter.Frame(master=window) 
f.pack(side=tkinter.TOP)
```

Так можно сделать несколько объектов-рамок, в которые можно размещать виджеты. В каждой рамке - или pack или grid! Если делать как в моем примере - то все рамки на главном окне следует также упаковывать методом pack.